# React My component does not render on page load

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to build a datepicker and whenever I change state from react dev tools it loads otherwise it does not. I am not very experienced in react. But I have built a prototype in Vuejs and it's working there
This is my code.

```
  const [dates, setDates] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    setMonthYear()
    getDatesInMonth()
  }, [month, year, dates])
  
  const setMonthYear = () => {
    var d = new Date()
    setMonth(d.getMonth())
    setYear(d.getFullYear())
    console.log(month)
    console.log(year)
  }

  //get all the dates in specified month
  const getDatesInMonth = () => {
    var date = new Date(year, month);

    const arrayValue = dates
    if(dates.length === 0){
      while(date.getMonth() === month){
        arrayValue.push(new Date(date).toString())
        setDates(arrayValue)
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
      }
      console.log(dates)
    }
    else{
      dates.length = 0
      while(date.getMonth() === month){
        arrayValue.push(new Date(date).toString())
        setDates(arrayValue)
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
      }
      console.log(dates)
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {dates && dates.map(function(date, index) {
        return <h2 key={index}>{date}</h2>
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Can you add ALL of your component and a screen / exemple of your problem

Answer (score 0):

Replace arrayValue = dates  to  arrayValue = [] and remove elseBlock

```
const [dates, setDates] = useState([])
const [month, setMonth] = useState([])
const [year, setYear] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
  setMonthYear()
  getDatesInMonth()
}, [month, year, dates])

const setMonthYear = () => {
  var d = new Date()
  setMonth(d.getMonth())
  setYear(d.getFullYear())
}

const getDatesInMonth = () => {
  var date = new Date(year, month);

const arrayValue = []
  if(dates.length === 0){
    while(date.getMonth() === month){
        arrayValue.push(new Date(date).toString())
        setDates(arrayValue)
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
    }
  }
}
return (
  <div className="App">
    {dates && dates.map(function(date, index) {
      return <h2 key={index}>{date}</h2>
    })}
  </div>
);
```

Comment: check this link it works fine [SandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-dust-p80g5?from-embed)